# FancyBox2 iFrame not loading

Tags: iframe, fancybox

I am using a link to send an href/url to a Fancybox javascript function. I have had this working fine with Fancybox v1 but on upgrading to v2 it no longer works. I have copied the code directly from their website but still I just get an empty white iFrame (no error messages).

```
document.getElementById('link_'+box_name).innerHTML = '<a class="various fancybox.iframe" onmouseover="this.style.cursor=\'pointer\';" href="javascript:display2(\'http://jquery.com\')">test</a>';

function display2(url) {    
$(".various").fancybox({        
    'href': url,
    maxWidth    : 820,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});             
}
```

Comment: I have tried: href : url, but the quotes made no difference...

Comment: I have tried: type :'iframe', but no change

Answer (score 2):

I made a few changes & got this to work:

```
document.getElementById('link_'+box_name).innerHTML = '<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" onmouseover="this.style.cursor=\'pointer\';" href="javascript:display2(\'http://jquery.com\')">test</a>';

function display2(url) {    
    $.fancybox({        
        href        : url,
        type        :'iframe',
        maxWidth    : 820,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });             
}
```